# Assert that for every value of a const array, an object has a key

Tags: typescript

```
const supported = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

```
const someObject = {a: 2, b: 3}; // I want TS to throw: error, has no 'c'!
```

I've got a const array of strings. How do I assert that an object's keys cover all the values?

Comment: What should happen for `const someObject = {a: 2, b: 3, c: undefined};`?

Comment: You could do: `const allKeysExist = supported.forEach(key => someObject.hasOwnProperty(key)); // true or false`

Comment: @mjwills I'll be happy with either solution.

Comment: @Joel I'm looking for a pure TS solution.

Comment: @zerkms Perfect, thank you. Please post this as a solution, so I can accept it. And out of pure curiosity, is it doable without helper types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
const supported = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;

const someObject: Record<typeof supported[number], number> = {a: 2, b: 3};
```

It enforces all values to be numbers and the object to have all the keys from `supported`.

You surely can relax the type of the values to be `unknown` or `any`.

If you for some reason don't want to use the built-in `Record<K, V>` type you can always expand it to `{ [P in typeof supported[number]]: number }`.

Important note: the `supported` value must be known compile time.

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=43#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuAHRIBOUCmATGBeGA2gEQCGRANDEQEYVXBEC6MJEMokUA3ALABQ-DtDggAthgDy1AFYZgUAFwwASnLRYAPFACeiDCABmcJCnTYCYeKOoZUjSpeu2AfHhgBvEkoBMlakoBmAF8uGAB6MJgASRgAdxIwWAAVAGUYKBB0gAtUEFilW1zUSizWGDBMgHJgSoBCIA

*Update*:

a solution to have some keys optional:

```
const supported = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] as const;

type Keys = typeof supported[number];
type OptionalKeys = "d" | "e";
type MandatoryKeys = Exclude<Keys, OptionalKeys>

const someObject: Record<MandatoryKeys, number> & Partial<Record<OptionalKeys, number>>  = {a: 2, b: 3, c: 42};
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuAHRIBOUCmATGBeGA2gEQCGRANDEQEYVXB1FaMZEC6MJEMokUA3AFgAUCKgBPRBhgBpDOO74JUkADM4SFOmwEw8ALbUMqNkOHLpAeURQAluBIAbOQrxVmMAD5VWZizABZEjAsEig0cRdFGABRAA9gR3gsDAAeKMprOwdneQgAPhERXmg4EH0MS2oAKwxgKAAuGAAlOrQsVKCQsIiMmD1DY3yYADIYAAUSdFsnVNbQVA6s+zAnPoGjVHzhtwBvEiaAJkpqJoBmSmAmgBZDgF9+IA

Comment: What if I wanted all of the keys be present in the array, but not the entire array should be covered? I.e. adding `d` would throw, but not adding `c` is fine.